# nuxt3: how to access fetched data in page middleware

Tags: nuxt.js, vuejs3, nuxtjs3

I'm working on a Nuxt 3 project, and I have a question about the syntax in one of my files.

(I want to make it more SEO-friendly, so instead of using `pages/posts/[id].vue`, I'm using `pages/posts/[id]/[title].vue`.)

Here's the code in the `setup` section of `pages/posts/[id]/[title].vue`:

```js
type Post {
    title: string;
};

const route = useRoute();

const { data } = await useFetch(
    `/posts/${route.params.id}`
) as {
    data: Ref<Post>
};

definePageMeta({
    middleware: [
        (to: RouteLocationNormalized, from: RouteLocationNormalized) => {

            // I want to access the fetched data here
            if (to.params.title !== data.value.title) {
                navigateTo(`/posts/${data.value.id}/${data.value.title}`);
            }
        }
    ]
});
```

However, when I run the code, I receive a **`500` error with the message "data is not defined."** I know that I can fetch the post data in middleware independently, but it would result in duplicate requests, which is not ideal.

How can I improve my code to make it works and send the request only once?

Thanks a lot for anyone helps!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need to store the data, I'm new to Nuxt and had the same question today and ended up figuring out a few minutes ago.

In your middleware:

```
const $store = useNuxtApp()
$store.$requestData = data.value
```

Then, in your page:

```
<script setup>

    const $store = useNuxtApp()
    console.log('data', $store.$requestData)
    const data = $store.$requestData;

</script>
```

Of course I'm still very new to Nuxt (or JS frameworks in general), and any better solution would be welcome, in case I'm missing something here.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer! With the help of your anwser and some other post, I finally figure it out. Your answer may add `callWithNuxt()` which is necessary when you use `await` in middleware

Answer (score 0):

With [@joelod's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76357173/10519069) and the followings:

- [the discuss in reddit: **USing Pinia with firebase composable in SSR**](https://www.reddit.com/r/Nuxt/comments/132r2up/using_pinia_with_firebase_composable_in_ssr/)
- [the GitHub issue: **nuxtApp.call**](https://github.com/nuxt/nuxt/issues/14805#issue-1549639017)

Here is the solution:

```
import { useNuxtApp, callWithNuxt } from '#app';

// fetch the post data only once in middleware instead of the outside
definePageMeta({
    middleware: [
        async (to: RouteLocationNormalized, from: RouteLocationNormalized) => {

            const nuxtApp = useNuxtApp();

            const { data: post } = await useFetch<Post>(
                `/posts/${to.params.id}`
            );

            await callWithNuxt(
                nuxtApp,
                () => {
                    nuxtApp.$requestData = post.value;
                }
            );
        }
    ]
});

const nuxtApp = useNuxtApp();
const route = useRoute();

const post = ref<Post>(nuxtApp.$requestData as Post);

if (to.params.title !== post.value.title) {
    navigateTo(`/posts/${post.value.id}/${post.value.title}`);
}

// then you can use the `post` data anywhere
useSeoMeta({
    title: `${post.value.title} | My Blog`,
});
```

PS:

Writing `navigateTo()` outside of the middleware may be a better practice because when `useFetch` received an error, such as `404 Not Found` or `429 Too Many Requests`, the page could get `[nuxt] A composable that requires access to the Nuxt instance was called outside of a plugin, Nuxt hook, Nuxt middleware, or Vue setup function` if `navigateTo()` is inside of the middleware, since your `template` may use the `post` data.